# SQL Server lock preventing updates in transaction C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, locking

I'm having an issue with a procedure that queries an item, and updates it in a loop. What happens is after the SELECT queries the items table, and updates the first item, whenever it comes around the 2nd time to query and update the next item, the SELECT query times out.

```
using (IDbConnection dbConn = sql.createConnection(ProgOps.connectionString))
       {
       // Start Transaction
       dbConn.Open();
       IDbTransaction dbTrans = sql.createTransaction(dbConn);

        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {
            // Get Item Dataset
            dbDataset =  sql.searchItemDetails(itemID[i]);     // SELECT * FROM Items WHERE itemID = @itemID

            // Update Item
            await sql.updateItem(itemID[i], dbConn, dbTrans);  // UPDATE Items SET price = @price WHERE itemID = @itemID
            }
       }
```

Looking at the processes in SSMS the items table wait type is in LCK_M_S which leads me to believe the table is locked preventing any more selects from occurring. I would assume that if each update was a row lock and not a page lock I would still be able to query and update other items correct? Anyways I'm unsure how to add these modifications to the transaction and individual queries using the code above, any suggestions are appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Kinda magic. Session/transaction cannot block itself. There must be more than one connection... Does the connection remain the same after first iteration? You can easily check this by querying `select @@SPID`.

Comment: dbDataset =  sql.searchItemDetails(itemID[i]);  is on a separate connection than await sql.updateItem(itemID[i], dbConn, dbTrans).... I'll try them on the same connection and see how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not entirely sure, but i can see how this code would lock.  The transaction + a loop + a read + an update is pretty messy.  Is there a reason you need to loop through this in a transaction? I would rewrite to this and see if it helps

```
using (IDbConnection dbConn = sql.createConnection(ProgOps.connectionString))
{
   // Start Transaction
   dbConn.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        // Get Item Dataset
        dbDataset =  sql.searchItemDetails(itemID[i]);     // SELECT * FROM Items WHERE itemID = @itemID

        IDbTransaction dbTrans = sql.createTransaction(dbConn);
        // Update Item
        await sql.updateItem(itemID[i], dbConn, dbTrans);  // UPDATE Items SET price = @price WHERE itemID = @itemID

        dbTrans.Commit(); // i think this is the command, pulling from memory
    }
}
```

If you need all of the updates to be a single transaction then I would update this code to do a bulk update instead of updating a single line at a time. 
Good luck

Comment: This is a snippet of a larger transaction procedure that updates the customer table as well as an invoice table. The location of creating the transaction itself shouldn't be that much of an issue, but I was hoping there may be a way to modify how the locking works for the individual items table so I could continue to gather items and update them individually. I see what you mean though, my best bet may be too gather all the items in one large SELECT statement and then update them that way.

Comment: in sql server you can write a select statement to tell it to not lock the table (record).  Its "SELECT blah From ITEMS WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE blah='foo'"

Comment: Thanks dude that was just what i was looking for!

Comment: the downside is that you are basically telling sql to get you potentially dirty data.  Glad it helps.

Comment: Yeah I can see how it could be bad, but for my specific application it should work great! :)